# reorder 2-d list according to the second value of each element

Tags: list-manipulation, order

I have a nested list with n row and 2 column, its values are numbers, Can I change the order of elements according to the second value?? so every element have in its second value the same value in the first of the next element
Example:

```
y = {{1,4}, {2,3}, {4,2}, {3,1}}
```

I want to start from the element contains 1, then it contains 4, I want to put the element contains 4 as its first value after it  so it would be {4,2}, and the next must be {2,3}, and so on...

```
output = {{1,4}, {4,2}, {2,3}, {3,1}}
```

the elements always contains two values only
is there any function can do this or I must do this manually????
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
y = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 1}};
```

If the input list is pairs of integers, you can use [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html):

```
y[[FindHamiltonianPath[y]]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}
> ```

In general, you can construct a list of `UndirectedEdge`s from the input list and use a combination of `FindHamiltonianPath` and `Partition`:

```
y2 = N @ y
```

> ```
> {{1., 4.}, {2., 3.}, {4., 2.}, {3., 1.}}
> ```

```
Partition[FindHamiltonianPath[UndirectedEdge @@@ y2], 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{1., 4.}, {4., 2.}, {2., 3.}}
> ```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I want, because this is the solution for the optimal path of TSP problem and I want to construct the hamilton path from variables in solution